# regular expression of 3 groups check

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like a group of 3 values in the following regular expression and input string

With the help of the SO experts this is what I have:

```
string item = "strawb bana 1 10 1.93";
string pattern = @"(?<str>[\w\s]*)(?<qty>\s\d*\s)(?<num>\d*\.\d+)";
```

Basically,

The first value is going to be the product description. I put a 1 on the end just in case the description has a number in it.

The second value is the quantity.

The third value is price.

Does this look correct? Might I be missing other cases?

Result should be the following

```
Group 1 = "strawb bana 1"
Group 2 = "10"
Group 3 = "1.93"
```

Comment: Why don't you try it on a bunch of test data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to include digits in your first match.

```
string item = "strawb bana 1 10 1.93";
string pattern = @"(?<str>[\w\s]*)(?<qty>\s\d*\s)(?<num>\d*\.\d+)";
```

Should be:

```
string item = "strawb bana 1 10 1.93";
string pattern = @"(?<str>[\w\s\d]*)(?<qty>\s\d*\s)(?<num>\d*\.\d+)";
```